# How do I setup react-resize-detector's HOC in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to setup my component to use the react-resize-detector's `withResizeDetector` wrapper, but I can't find an example of how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the `index.d.ts` file, I found that there is not export for the props to extend, so I had to create them manually.

This worked for me:

```
type Props = 
    IProps & {
        height: number;
        width: number;
    };
```

Where `IProps` is your components existing props.

I used a functional component, so the declaration was:

```
const EventSnapshotPane: React.FC<Props> = ({
    ... other props from IProps
    width,
    height,
}) => {
```

And finally, the export

```
export default withResizeDetector(EventSnapshotPane);
```

I actually use redux and Google MUI, so my export was a bit more complex, but here it is for anyone else using those two

```
export default withStyles(styles)(connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {},
)(withResizeDetector(EventSnapshotPane)));
```